# Wagtail 2.2 references API v1

Tags: wagtail

I've just upgraded to Wagtail 2.2 and I'm getting an error 'wagtailadmin_api_v1 is not a registered namespace'.  Part of the upgrade moved to api_v2 (which is in my INSTALLED_APPS).  I did a search of the Wagtail code and found references to api_v1 in wagtail.admin.api.urls and wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/admin_base.html (there were several others in tests).  I changed the references to V2, but then got the same error claiming that 'wagtail_api_v2 is not a registered namespace.

My question is whether anyone else has seen a similar problem and second, should there be **any** references to api_v1 in Wagtail 2.2

Comment: Which version of Wagtail did you upgrade *from*?

Comment: ...Also, what version of Django are you running?

Comment: I upgraded from Wagtail 2.1, running Django 2.0.7.  I've done a good bit more looking and I see 'wagtailadmin_api_v1 ' referenced in the template wagtailadmin/admin_base.html and also in api/urls.py.  I've tried changing to 'v2', but that doesn't seem to be right.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error while integrating `Wagtail 2.5` to an existing `Django 2.2` project. My mistake was including Wagtail's urls to a namespaced `urls.py`.

The `wagtailadmin_api_v1` is set on [wagtail/admin/api/urls.py](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/api/urls.py)

According to the docs for [url-configuration](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html#url-configuration) , you must include those patterns on your main `urls.py`.

```
~/projects/project_name/
manage.py           
project_name/       
  my_app/
    models.py
    urls.py         # Those are app-specific urls
    views.py           
    __init__.py
    ...
  settings.py
  urls.py           # This is the urls.py you should modify
  wsgi.py
  __init__.py
  ...
```

Pattern to be included:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, include

from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'^cms/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    re_path(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
    re_path(r'^pages/', include(wagtail_urls)),
    ...
]
```

Be sure to include those patterns on your main `urls.py` (it shouldn't set an `app_name` variable, or all the patterns will be automatically namespaced.)

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled over the same issue today and this worked for me:

```py
# api views.py
from wagtail.api.v2.router import WagtailAPIRouter
from wagtail.api.v2.views import PagesAPIViewSet

wagtail_api_router = WagtailAPIRouter("cast:api:wagtail")
wagtail_api_router.register_endpoint("pages", PagesAPIViewSet)

# local urls.py
app_name = "api"
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    # wagtail api
    path("wagtail/", include((views.wagtail_api_router.get_urlpatterns(), "api"), namespace="wagtail")),
]
```

Reverse looks now like this:

```py
reverse("cast:api:wagtail:pages:listing")
```